# Can I shorten this formula and make it faster?

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, gs-vlookup

I have a Google Spreadsheet that imports my bank transactions. (the language here is Dutch)

I put this formula on cell P2 so I can categorize the transactions.

```
=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(IFS(
E2:E="IOB";"Interne boekingen";
E2:E="GEA";"Geldautomaat"; 
REGEXMATCH(F2:F;Instellingen!$B$2);Instellingen!$A$2;
REGEXMATCH(F2:F;Instellingen!$B$3);Instellingen!$A$3;
REGEXMATCH(F2:F;Instellingen!$B$4);Instellingen!$A$4;
REGEXMATCH(F2:F;Instellingen!$B$5);Instellingen!$A$5;
REGEXMATCH(F2:F;Instellingen!$B$6);Instellingen!$A$6;
REGEXMATCH(F2:F;Instellingen!$B$7);Instellingen!$A$7;
REGEXMATCH(F2:F;Instellingen!$B$8);Instellingen!$A$8
);""))
```

So in tab Instellingen (Settings) I have the regex code in col $B$2 and the description in col $A$2.

And the next regex code is in instellingen!$B$3 and description in Instellingen!$A$3, and so on.

Can I shorten this formula?

And I have about 2000 lines on this sheet so this formula is very slow, can I solve this somehow?

And here is a stripped version of my sheet: [Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1562zm_Twofo98rzTkL1mi_bnZu5RJTH7htzgqKjdiKo/edit?usp=sharing)

- Import tab is the imported text from the bank
- Instellingen(settings) here are the regex codes with descriptions
- Overzicht (Overview) is the query formula in A1 and G2 has the array formula

you can edit the sheet btw

Comment: Can you share a copy of your spreadsheet with a sample of the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this may be not shorter but it's faster:

```
={"Alias"; ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(A2:A); 
 IF(E2:E="IOB"; "Interne boekingen";
 IF(E2:E="GEA"; "Geldautomaat";
 IFERROR(VLOOKUP(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(LOWER(F2:F); 
 REGEXEXTRACT(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(QUERY(LOWER(
 SUBSTITUTE(Instellingen2!B2:B; " "; "♦"))&IF(LEN(Instellingen2!B2:B); "," ; )
 ; ; 999^99); ","; "|"); " "; ""); "♦"; " "); "(.*)\|$")));
 QUERY(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY("♂"&LOWER(TRIM(IFERROR(
 SPLIT(Instellingen2!B2:B; ","))))&"♀"&Instellingen2!A2:A; ; 999^99)); ; 999^99); 
 "♂")); "♀"); "where Col2 is not null"; 0); 2; 0)))); ))}
```

[image: 0]

### [demo spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19gjzCVpX5utellK5UJV4jNHhnQCwrfWKaiM2iUwCnTo/edit#gid=372455223)

and it also requires to do list of items this way:

[image: 0]

Comment: wow that looks great, but somehow it doesn't work for me, the only result that I get is in line 2 and 3 of your formula (IOB and GEA) I think reason is that there are a view special characters in your formula like: 
SUBSTITUTE(Instellingen2!B2:B; " "; "♦") and
Instellingen2!A2:A; ; 999^99)); ; 999^99); 
 "♂")); "♀");
is this a conversion error like me living in Europe and your'e not?

Comment: nope, those characters are there on purpose. it not working for you probably coz of "Instellingen2" instead of "Instellingen". I included a demo spreadsheet for you so you would be able to examine it.

Comment: oops my bad :-) made a little mistake, it works now, its a nice improvement, thanks man